# Implement type checking of vertex properties in Vertex classes

Tags: php, laravel, gremlin

I have a laravel server and in my laravel server i have vertex classes that represents vertex labels in my GRAPH database.

All my vertex classes is extended to a Gremlin class that has an orm implementation of gremlin steps.

My problem is that my graph database arent really strict with data types of its properties, and i want to add another layer in my vertex classes that checks the data types of properties that goes into it.

This is my Gremlin class

```
<?php
namespace App\Database;
use \Brightzone\GremlinDriver\Connection;
use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;

use App\Enums\EdgesEnum;
use App\Enums\DetailTypeEnum;

use App\Database\Vertices\Detail;

class Gremlin 
{
    protected $db;
    protected $partitionKey = 'pk';
    protected $queryBuilder;
    protected $vertexLabel;

    function __construct($username = null) {
        $this->db = new Connection([
            'host' => config('graphdb.defaults.host'),
            'username' => $username ? $username : config('graphdb.defaults.username'),
            'password' => config('graphdb.defaults.password'),
            'port' => config('graphdb.defaults.port'),
            'ssl' => config('graphdb.defaults.ssl')
        ]);
    }

    public function getDb(){
        return $this->db;
    }

    public function g() {
        $this->queryBuilder = "g";
        return $this;
    }

    public function label() {
        return $this->vertexLabel;
    }

    public function V($value = null) {
        $subquery = '';
        
        if ($value) {
            $subquery = "'".$value."'";
        }
        
        $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".V($subquery)";
            
        return $this;
    }

    public function E($value = null) {
        $subquery = '';
        
        if ($value) {
            $subquery = "'".$value."'";
        }
        
        $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".E($subquery)";
            
        return $this;
    }

    public function by(...$values) {

        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
            if($index != 0 && ($value =='incr' || $value =='decr')){
                $subquery = $subquery."$value,";
            } else {
                $subquery = $subquery.$this->getSubQueryByValue($value).",";
            }
            
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);
            
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".by($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."by($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function limit($value) {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".limit($value)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."limit($value)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function where($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);
            
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".where($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."where($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function valueMap(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery. ($value === true ? 'true' : "'$value'").",";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".valueMap($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."valueMap($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function has($property, $value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".has('$property', $subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."has('$property', $subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function _has($property) {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".has('$property')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."has('$property')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function order() {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".order()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."order()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function choose(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery. $this->getSubQueryByValue($value).",";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".choose($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."choose($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function is($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".is($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."is($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function inside($value1, $value2) {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".inside($value1, $value2)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."inside($value1, $value2)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function option($value, $traversal) {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".option(".$this->getSubQueryByValue($value).", ".$this->getSubQueryByValue($traversal).")";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."option(".$this->getSubQueryByValue($value).", ".$this->getSubQueryByValue($traversal).")";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasId($id) {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".hasId('$id')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."hasId('$id')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuery(){
        return $this->queryBuilder;
    }

    public function queryBuilder(){
        return $this->queryBuilder;
    }

    public function setQueryBuilder($value) {
        $this->queryBuilder = $value;
    }

    public function from($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".from($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."from($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;       
    }

    public function sideEffect($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".sideEffect($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."sideEffect($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;       
    }

    public function repeat($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".repeat($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."repeat($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;   
    }

    public function emit($value=null) {
        $subquery = '';

        if($value) {
            $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);
        }

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".emit($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."emit($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;   
    }

    private function getSubQueryByValue($value) {
        $subquery = '';

        switch (gettype($value)) {
            case 'string':
            case 'NULL':
                $subquery = $subquery."'".addslashes($value)."'";
                break;
            case 'boolean':
                $subquery = $subquery.($value ? 'true' : 'false');
                break;
            case 'object':
                if(is_callable($value)) {
                    $subquery = $subquery.call_user_func_array($value, [new $this])->queryBuilder();
                }
                break;
            default:
                $subquery = $subquery.$value;
                break;
        }

        return $subquery;
    }

    public function to($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".to($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."to($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;  
    }

    public function addV($value) {
        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".addV('$value')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."addV('$value')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function property($property, $value) {
        switch (gettype($value)) {
            case 'string':
            case 'NULL':
                $value = "'" . addslashes($value) . "'";
                break;
            case 'boolean':
                $value = $value ? "true" : "false";
                break;
        }

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".property('$property', $value)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."property('$property', $value)";
        }
        
        return $this;
    }

    public function propertyWithNoSlashes($property, $value) {         
        if (gettype($value) == 'string' || gettype($value) == 'NULL') {
            $value = "'" . $value . "'";
        } else if (gettype($value) == 'boolean') {
            $value = $value ? "true" : "false";
        }


        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".property('$property', $value)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."property('$property', $value)";
        }
            
        return $this;
    }

    public function properties(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery."'".$value."',";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".properties($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."properties($subquery)";
        }
            
        return $this;
    }

    public function as($value) {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".as('$value')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."__.as('$value')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addE($label) {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".addE('$label')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."addE('$label')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function group() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".group()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."group()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function isDirty($initalVertex, $updatedVertex) {
        foreach ($initalVertex as $key => $value) {
            
            if(isset($updatedVertex[$key]) ) {
                if($updatedVertex[$key] != $value){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    public function softDeleteWithLog($vertexids, $geolocation) {
        $query = 'g.V()';
        
        foreach ($vertexids as $key => $id) {
            $this->db->open();

            $query = "g.V().hasId('$id')
                .property('deleted_at', ".time().")
                .addE('".EdgesEnum::DELETED."')
                .property('longitude', ".($geolocation['longitude'] ? $geolocation['longitude'] : "''").")
                .property('latitude', ".($geolocation['latitude'] ? $geolocation['latitude'] : "''").")
                .property('date', ".time().")
                .from(g.V('".auth()->user()->id."'))";
            
            $result = $this->db->send($query);

            $this->db->close();

            $query = "";
        }

        return;
    }

    public function unfold() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".unfold()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."unfold()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function fold() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".fold()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."fold()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function select(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if($value == 'keys' || $value == 'values') {
                $subquery = $subquery."$value,";
            } else {
                $subquery = $subquery."'$value',";
            }
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".select($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."select($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function values(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery."'$value',";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".values($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."values($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function out(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery."'$value',";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".out($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."out($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function in($value = null) {
        if($value) {
            $value = "'".$value."'";
        }

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".in($value)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."__.in($value)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function inE($value = null) {
        if($value) {
            $value = "'".$value."'";
        }

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".inE($value)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."__.inE($value)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function outE($value = null) {
        if($value) {
            $value = "'".$value."'";
        }

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".outE($value)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."outE($value)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function inV() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".inV()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."__.inV()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function dedup() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".dedup()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."__.dedup()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function outV() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".outV()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."__.outV()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasNot($key) {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".hasNot('$key')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."hasNot('$key')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function coalesce(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';
        
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery.call_user_func_array($value, [new $this])->queryBuilder().",";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".coalesce($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."coalesce($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function union(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';
        
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery.call_user_func_array($value, [new $this])->queryBuilder().",";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".union($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."union($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function count() {
        $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".count()";

        $this->db->open();

        $result = $this->db->send($this->queryBuilder);

        $this->db->close();

        $this->queryBuilder = null;

        return $result;
    }

    public function _count() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".count()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."count()";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasLabel($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".hasLabel($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."hasLabel($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function get() {
        // try{
            $this->db->open();
        
            $result = $this->db->send($this->queryBuilder);
            
            $this->db->close();

            $this->queryBuilder = null; //set to null to reset query builder and be available to next queries

            return $result;
        // }catch(\Exception $e) {
        //     dd($this->queryBuilder);
        // }
    }

    public function or(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery. $this->getSubQueryByValue($value).",";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".or($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."or($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hydrateList($list) {
        $hydratedList = [];
        foreach ($list as $key => $vertex) {
            $tempVertex = [];
            
            foreach ($vertex as $property => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $tempVertex[$property] = $this->getActualValue($value[0]); 

                } else {
                    $tempVertex[$property] = $this->getActualValue($value);
                }
            }
            
            array_push($hydratedList, $tempVertex);
        }

        return $hydratedList;
    }

    protected function getActualValue($value) {
        if($value ==='null') {
            return null;
        }
        if($value === 'false') {
            return false;
        }
        if($value === 'true') {
            return true;
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function drop() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".drop()";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."drop()";
        }
            
        return $this;
    }

    public function range($x, $y) {
        $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".range($x, $y)";
            
        return $this;
    }

    public function partitionKey($value) {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".property('$this->partitionKey', '$value')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."property('$this->partitionKey', '$value')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function project(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery."'$value',";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".project($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."project($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function constant($value) {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".constant('$value')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."constant('$value')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    // Predicates
    public function without(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery."'$value',";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".without($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."without($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function eq($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".eq($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."eq($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function gt($value) {
        $subquery = $this->getSubQueryByValue($value);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".gt($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."gt($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function within(...$values) {
        $subquery = '';

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $subquery = $subquery.$this->getSubQueryByValue($value).",";
        }

        $subquery = substr($subquery, 0, -1);

        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".within($subquery)";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."within($subquery)";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function TextP() {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".TextP";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."TextP";
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function containing($value) {
        if ($this->queryBuilder) {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder.".containing('$value')";
        } else {
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->queryBuilder."containing('$value')";
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

and i have a Product Class that extends to Gremlin class. then when i want to save a product, i just do:

```
Product::g()->addV('product')
->property('pk', 'product')
->property('name', 'product1')
->property('sku', '123255')
->property('description', '')
->get();
```

The problem here is the `name`, `sku`, and `description` can be of many data types.

I want to add an implementation where the data types of properties can be limited to one data type but im not really sure whats the right way to do it.

Laravel version: "laravel/framework": "^8.0"
Php Version: "php": "^8.0",

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what graph database you use, but the best choice would be to use one that allows you to define a schema so that it is the database that handles data type enforcement and coercion. If you can't switch databases, then your query builder approach will need to simply type check all the arguments that can be expected to be of more than a single type and translate them to the appropriate form that Gremlin will understand. In TinkerPop, we do this sort of type checking in all of our [Translators](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#translators). You can see how it works here in Java for the `GroovyTranslator` [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.11/gremlin-groovy/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/jsr223/GroovyTranslator.java#L118). You can see a similar pattern in the Python `Translator` [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.5.0/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/process/translator.py), that also produces the Groovy form of Gremlin.